# Image request from URL fails

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have the following code:

```
func getImage(urlString: String, completionHandler: UIImage -> Void) -> NSURLSessionTask {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)!)

    println("Executing image request: \(urlString)")

    return session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            println("\tGET request failed: \(error!)")
        } else {
            println("\tGET request succeeded!")
            let response = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // dispatch naar main thread (main_queue is thread# van main thread van app)
                    completionHandler(image!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I execute it, I get the following output:

```
Executing image request: http://i.imgur.com/rfw7jrU.gif
GET request failed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1100.)" 
UserInfo=0x14e9b200 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///http:/i.imgur.com/rfw7jrU.gif,
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///http:/i.imgur.com/rfw7jrU.gif,
NSUnderlyingError=0x14d8d600 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1100.)"}
```

I have no idea why this happens, as my nearly identical code that gets a .json file does work. I have tested this on both my device and the simulator.

This fails on all urls, not only imgur links. It also crashes before I put it into a `UIImage`, so that is also not the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the error message one can see that your URL is a *file URL*:

```
file:///http:/i.imgur.com/rfw7jrU.gif
```

and error `-1100` is `kCFURLErrorFileDoesNotExist` (see [CFNetwork Error Codes Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors?language=objc)).

You should replace

```
NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)
```

by

```
NSURL(string: urlString)
// Swift 3+:
URL(string: urlString)
```

Comment: Okay, this solved my first problem, but now I'm getting a nonmoving image, and these are gifs. Is there any way I can make the images moving?

Comment: @vrwim: That is a completely different problem and unfortunately I cannot help you with that. Try googling for "iOS animated GIF".

Comment: Yeah, doing right now, just thought you might be of any help